# How to get rows and columns from text block

Tags: python

Hi I have following text block:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

I want to put columns and rows in different lists. I managed to make rows list because it is obvious but still struggling with columns.

```
rowsList = []
columnsList = []
block = open("asd.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
for line in block:
    rowsList.append(line)

#['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl']

for i in range(len(rowsList)):
    for j in range(len(rowsList[i])):
        ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` to achieve "transposing":

```py
with open('asd.txt', 'r') as f:
    rows = f.read().splitlines()

cols = [''.join(zipped) for zipped in zip(*rows)]

print(rows) # ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
print(cols) # ['aeim', 'bfjn', 'cgko', 'dhlp']
```

`zip(*rows)` would be equivalent  to `zip('abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop')`. At the first iteration in the list comprehension as an example, `zipped` will be `('a', 'e', 'i', 'm')` (a tuple consisting of the first characters in each row). `''.join(zipped)` then yields `'aeim'`.

If you prefer to use `for` with index-based idiom, the following basically achieves the same. However, this is generally not recommended (not pythonic!):

```py
cols = []
for i in range(len(rows)):
    col = []
    for j in range(len(rows[i])):
        col.append(rows[j][i])
    cols.append(''.join(col))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are completely correct right now. You just access the column as `rowsList[i][j]`.